# Im trying to upload an image in pygame with blit method but the image doesn't show up on the screen

Tags: python, image, pygame

So I'm basically just trying to upload an image in pygame with blit but it doesn't show up on the screen. I'm watching a youtube tutorial on this and I can't make the image go up on the screen. I double checked that I downloaded the image.

```
import pygame

# Define the background colour
# using RGB color coding.
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Define the dimensions of
# screen object(width,height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500))

# Set the caption of the screen
pygame.display.set_caption('Space game')

# Fill the background colour to the screen
screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.update()

# Update the display using flip
pygame.display.flip()

# Variable to keep our game loop running
running = True
#maximum the FPS can go up to
FPS = (60)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#loading the spaceship images
YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('images/spaceship_yellow.png')
RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('images/spaceship_red.png')

def draw_window():
    screen.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE(300, 100))
# game loop
while running:
#telling the game to run only at 60 FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)

    # for loop through the event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # Check for QUIT event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Modifying the `draw_window` function

The `blit` function takes two non optional parameters: the image that you want to display on the screen and the coordinates of that image. In your code, I see that you forgot to separate the two parameters with a comma.

### So change this:

```
def draw_window():
    screen.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE(300, 100))
```

### To this:

```
def draw_window():
    screen.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (300, 100))
```

## Modifying the game loop

In the game loop (the `while running` loop), you aren't calling the `draw_window` function. In addition, you aren't updating the display. If you apply these changes, your sprite will be drawn on the screen as expected.

### Another change you need to make:

Below your event loop, you will need to add the following lines:

```
pygame.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

You have to add this because when `running` is `False`, you need the program to stop running. Don't forget to import the `sys` module, like this: `import sys`

### Modified game loop:

```
# game loop
while running:
    # Fill the background colour to the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    # for loop through the event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for QUIT event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    draw_window()
    #telling the game to run only at 60 FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

## Full Code

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()

# Define the background colour
# using RGB color coding.
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Define the dimensions of
# screen object(width,height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500))

# Set the caption of the screen
pygame.display.set_caption('Space game')

# Variable to keep our game loop running
running = True
#maximum the FPS can go up to
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#loading the spaceship images
YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('images/spaceship_yellow.png')
RED_SPACESHIP_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('images/spaceship_red.png')

def draw_window():
    screen.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP_IMAGE, (300, 100))

# game loop
while running:
    # Fill the background colour to the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    # for loop through the event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for QUIT event
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    draw_window()
    #telling the game to run only at 60 FPS
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Nitpick: you don't need `sys.exit(0)`, it's just a convenience function to terminate your program. It's exactly the same as letting the program end naturally. `pygame.quit()` is only needed if you want to uninitialized `pygame` but still have your program running. So you don't have to add them.